# Can Amber Prison prevent multiple permanents from untapping?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Amber Prison](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Amber%20Prison) reads

> You may choose not to untap Amber Prison during your untap step.
>
> 4, Tap: Tap target artifact, creature, or land. That permanent doesn't untap during its controller's untap step for as long as Amber Prison remains tapped.

If during my turn I tap a creature, and then on my next turn I untap Amber Prison and use it to tap another creature, do both creatures remain tapped during the next untap phase?

If not, why not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only way it can be done is by copying the ability (such as through [Rings of Brighthearth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRings%20of%20Brighthearth%5d).  With just one copy of the ability, it works as follows:

"As long as" denotes the duration of the continuous effect. The effect ends when Amber Prison is untapped, and when it ends, there is nothing preventing the first creature from untapping.

> 611.2a A continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability lasts as long as stated by the spell or ability creating it
>   (such as “until end of turn”). If no duration is stated, it lasts
>   until the end of the game.

Even if Amber Prison is  untapped while its ability is on the stack and activated again, it wouldn't be possible, becase the effect from the first instance of the ability would not even start:

> 611.2b Some continuous effects generated by the resolution of a spell or ability have durations worded “for as long as . . . .” If the “for
>   as long as” duration never starts, or **it ends before the moment the
>   effect would first be applied, the effect does nothing**. It doesn’t
>   start and immediately stop again, and it doesn’t last forever.

Comment: So you're saying the effect ends when the Amber Prison untaps (for whatever reason)? Does that also mean if my opponent forces an untap (e.g. with [Twiddle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=45235)), then the creature is freed, unless I retarget it?

Comment: @ire_and_curses Yes, the effect will end as soon as it untaps, no matter the reason.

Comment: It's a bit of a niche effect but using an effect that copies the activated ability of the Amber Prison you can choose a new target and both will remain tapped until the Amber Prison is untapped  (Rings of Brighthearth can do this).

Comment: @Pablo is this also correct considering untapping with the ability on the stack? e.g. activate amber prison, untap with voltaic key with the tap ability on the stack, and tap again targeting another permanent. This is not dissimilar to the special case of removing oblivion ring style permanents before their exile trigger resolves, but I believe it may well work differently, so it's probably worth including in this answer.

Comment: Turning it into a creature and equiping it with illusionists bracers would be another long shot but a way to make it able to tap more than one.

Comment: @ire_and_curses, Yes, that's completely correct.

Comment: @Rawrgramming If you untap with the ability on the stack, the continuous portion of the ability does nothing: 611.2b " ... If the “for as long as” duration never starts, or it ends before the moment the effect would first be applied, the effect does nothing. ... "

Comment: @Affe yeah, there was a second answer for a while where we established the rule 611.2b stuff, but the answerer deleted it rather than editing to provide the additional information. I was pretty sure this was how it worked but I wasnt 100%, and I thought it was definitely worth including in the answer to the question.